# Choose random file in Maxscript

Tags: randomaccessfile, maxscript

How to choose any random file from a folder using  MaxScript?

```
files = getFiles "c:\\base\\*.max"
for f in files do random (mergeMAXFile f)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
i = random 1 files.count
mergeMAXfile files[i]
```